# APK has not been signed with the upload certificate

Tags: android, xamarin

This error occurs on the Visual Studio 2019, at Build > Archive process

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you generate an upload key and keystore and sign your application with it ?

Comment: yes, I generated keystore by Android Studio, and, add the certificate in keystore using the follow command at prompt keytool -importcert -file upload_cert.der -keystore upload-keystore.jks ...the file upload_cert.der downloaded from google console